# Issue with IdentityServer4 upgrade to .NET Core 2.0 (AddConfigurationStore, AddOperationalStore)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-2.0, identityserver4

I upgraded from .NET Core 1.1 to .NET Core 2.0 and encountered the following issue (I also upgraded a few libraries to support .net core 2.0 aswell)

CS1929  'ConfigurationStoreOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseNpgsql' and the best extension method overload 'NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseNpgsql(DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, Action)' requires a receiver of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder'

Startup.cs

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(Certificate.Get())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(builder =>
                builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddOperationalStore(builder =>
                builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

Same issue when using UseSqlServer

```
// configure identity server with in-memory users, but EF stores for clients and resources
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
    .AddConfigurationStore(builder =>
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
            options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
    .AddOperationalStore(builder =>
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
            options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html

Note: I have added "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;"

Comment: 2.0.0 RC1 was just released to nuget that targets netstandard 2.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(Certificate.Get())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem myself. A trawling of the IndentityServer4.EntityFramework github revealed an example [Startup.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Host/Startup.cs) making the use of the ConfigureDBContext property